# Using "Case When" in an "Order by" Clause that sort the result set based on multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to use Case When in an Order By clause but I want to sort the result set on more than one column. when I use the following syntax, I get syntax error.

```
Select * From MyTable
   ORDER BY 
     CASE 
        WHEN @ColumnName='NameAndId' THEN Name,Id
        WHEN @ColumnName='TitleAndId' THEN Title,Id
    END Desc
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax?

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your case only switches between `Name` and `Title` so you can move the `Id` out of the case statement.

Not sure where you want to apply `desc`. This will order by `Name` or `Title` descending and for the ties it will order on `Id` ascending.

```
Select * From MyTable
   ORDER BY 
     CASE 
        WHEN @ColumnName='NameAndId' THEN Name
        WHEN @ColumnName='TitleAndId' THEN Title
     END Desc, Id
```

Comment: @Mikeal: Is there any way to have multiple columns on decision parts of case when statement?

Comment: @VahidGhadiri - Yes, but you need to duplicate the `case` statement for each column you need to order by.